# Onde trocar o nome do projeto?

Tags: java, eclipse

tenho um projeto com o seguinte link http://localhost:8080/Confiabilidade/Home.xhtml . Ocorre que o verdadeiro nome deveria ser http://localhost:8080/PrevisaoVendas/Home.xhtml onde eu poderia trocar o nome no Eclipse?

Comment: Você quer alterar o contexto de de Confiablidade para PrevisaoVendas certo? Qual servidor está usando?

Comment: Estou uando o Tomcat 8.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso varia conforme o servidor.

---

### Tomcat

Deve-se alterar o `context root` nas propriedades do projeto. Para isso, acesse as propriedades do projeto (ALT + ENTER) e selecione *Web Project Settings*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

### JBoss

No caso do JBoss é necessário adicionar o arquivo `jboss-web.xml` dentro de `WEB-INF` com o conteúdo:

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>PrevisaoVendas</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

---

Para os demais servidores eu não sei como funciona. Sempre mexi com esses dois apenas.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro do arquivo `pom.xml` você pode encontrar essas configurações, basta modificar:

```
<groupId>br.com.home</groupId>
<artifactId>PrevisaoVendas</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>PrevisaoVendas</name>
```

Comment: @diegofm encotra? tá gripado?

Comment: @Blogueira não foi erro meu, foi do autor, eu só removi o snippet.